Reactor kafka: Consume messages, save to database and after insertion perform another action
Simply what I would like to achieve:

Consume messages from kafka
Save them to database
After making sure all messages are processed and saved. Use this table and perform another action.

My message model:
modelId: "12345"
itemList: [
   {
      "itemId": "9999"
   },
   {
      "itemId": "8888"
   }
]
   

and I will save modelId, itemId pair.
Each message header consists of is-transaction-end key and only on last message this flag is true. So I understand if last message is arrived, but it does not guarantee all messages is saved to database.
How my code looks like:
public void consumeAndSave() {
    Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, ModelItemEntity>> messages = kafkaReceiver.receive();
    AtomicBoolean isTransactionEnd = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    Flux<Void> flux = messages.flatMap(message -> {
        isTransactionEnd.set(message.headers().headers("is-transaction-end").equals("true"));
        var modelId = message.value().getModelId();
        var itemList = message.value().getItemList();
        return Flux.fromIterable(itemList)
                .flatMap(item -> {
                    ModelItemEntity entity = new ModelItemEntity();
                    entity.setModelId(modelId);
                    entity.setItemId(item.getId());
                    return modelItemRepository.save(entity);
                }).then();
    }).subscribe();

    if (isTransactionEnd.get()) {
        log.info("transaction end is arrived");

        //It needs to wait all database save process is completed
        flux.all().block

        log.info("db save is completed");
    }
}

It never returns from main flux. I just want to catch the moment after all db save operations are completed.
